# Software like support desk?

Tags: php

I need a software like helpdesk software, the script must be a standalone software means it must be installable on a web space. The key features are:

1. Every operator has own email address
2. **A customer must never access to request form, can simply send email to email from operator,d this operator will receive email and ticket will be opened?**
3. During conversation every reply will be inserted in ticket system
4. Operators has access only to own tickets

The 2. item is most important.